# Compose key not working in Chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, compose-key

(Once again) after upgrading to 16.04 Compose is broken. I fixed it in other apps following suggestions [on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1573755), but it doesn't help with Chrome. Any ideas?